# Test for pre-post test binary data for 3 groups

Tags: mcnemar-test, cochran-mantel-haenszel, cochran-q

I want to confirm what test to use for my data. I have three intervention groups. With the presence of a certain pathogen 1/0 (yes/no) before and after treatment. I want to analyze if there is a difference in the proportion of presence of pathogen before and after treatment by treatment group.

Should I use Cochran q? If so, I use Stata and downloaded the package *cochran* and *cochranq* but the help documents are brief and I don't know what syntax to use. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be easier to give a helpful answer if you could give specific examples. Within a group, are you looking at people who have the pathogen before treatment, but not after? Are you comparing numbers of 'cures' between two different treatment groups with different randomly assigned subjects?

Answer (score 0):

One possible scenario: Suppose you have 86 cures out of 200 in Gp 1, 75 out of 220 in Gp 2, and 66 out of 190 in Gp 3. Then you can use `prop.test` in R to test whether the cure rates
differ significantly (in a statistical sense)
among the three groups.

```
prop.test(c(86,75,66), c(200,220,190), cor=F)

        3-sample test for equality 
        of proportions without 
        continuity correction

data:  c(86, 75, 66) out of c(200, 220, 190)
X-squared = 4.283, df = 2, p-value = 0.1175
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
sample estimates:
    prop 1    prop 2    prop 3 
 0.4300000 0.3409091 0.3473684
```

The answer is that percentages of cures in the
three groups are 43.0%, 34.1%, and 34.7% in
Groups 1, 2, and 3, respectively. However,
the differences among groups are not statistically significant
at the 5% level of significance because
the P-value $0.1175 > 0.05 = 5/%.$

There may be actual differences among groups,
but sample sizes of the groups are not large
enough to claim statistical significance. Even if actual cure rates are the same among the three groups, similar patterns of differences among three groups could occur by random
chance with probability almost 12%.

A similar result would be found using a chi-squared
test of a $2 \times 3$ contingency table
of counts with rows Y/N and Columns for Groups 1,2,3.

If this is not what you have in mind, then please
edit your Question to clarify what data you have
and what you want to know.